# how to give a windows web server directory permissions?

Tags: c#, xml, permissions, webserver

I have a windows web server and i am using xml for the web.config i currently have extensions permissions set to false for .exe, .bin, and .dll

but i made a directory called "thing" with a .exe in it and i want to write in xml permissions for that directory that lets me download .exe files from it

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <configuration>
     <system.webServer>
         <security>
             <requestFiltering>
                 <fileExtensions>
                     <add fileExtension=".dll" allowed="false" />
                     <add fileExtension=".exe" allowed="false" />
                     <add fileExtension=".bin" allowed="false" />
                 </fileExtensions>
             </requestFiltering>
         </security>
     </system.webServer>
 </configuration>
```

help please?

Comment: What do you exactly want to do? Do you want to allow web clients to download .exe files from any public locations on the web server?

Comment: what is a windows web server? A program similar to Microsoft IIS ?

Comment: @ lorenzo yes i want that exactly i want it to let one or two folders let .exe files be downloaded from them but not for everywhere else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [IIS7 documentation](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/security/requestFiltering), there are 3 tags that you can use within `<requestFiltering>` to control URL access:

- `<denyUrlSequences>` - This element can contain a collection of URL sequence patterns that IIS 7 will deny; for example: you can deny parts of URL sequences that an attacker might try to exploit.
- `<fileExtensions>` - This element can contain a collection of file name extensions that IIS 7 will either deny or allow; for example: you can block all requests for Web.config files.`
- `<hiddenSegments>` - This element can contain a collection of URLs that cannot be browsed; for example: you can deny requests for the ASP.NET App_Code folder.

For example:

```
<requestFiltering>
    <!-- deny access to any URL which contains /private -->
    <denyUrlSequences>
       <add sequence="/private"/>
    </denyUrlSequences>
    <!-- block all file extensions except js,css,html -->
    <fileExtensions allowUnlisted="false">
       <add fileExtension=".js" allowed="true" />
       <add fileExtension=".css" allowed="true" />
       <add fileExtension=".html" allowed="true" />
    </fileExtensions>
    <!-- hide config and bin dir -->
    <hiddenSegments>
       <add segment="config" />
       <add segment="bin" />
    </hiddenSegments>
</requestFiltering>
```

You can hide some URLs or block some file extensions, but, as far as I can think, it is not possible to fine-tune the accessibility of specific file extensions by folder just changing the IIS configuration. If this is what you want, you'll probably need to write some server-side code.